# Unable to run SpecFlow on VS 2012

Tags: c#

I have just updated from VS 2010 to VS 2012.
I have installed specFlow 1.9 and NuGet package.
I have also installed specflow package through Manage NuGet packages.

Also configure my app.config to Ms test. Added all the required dll's and genereted the feature file as well as my .cs files.
But still im not able to run or Debug my the specFlow Tests.
While the same settinngs worked on VS 2010. And pressing F5 button also does not work.
Is there any Step that I am missing here or any setting that needs to be done prior to running the tests.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Found this post on the SpecFlow google group. Setting ReSharper as test runner tool made it work for me. I'm running SpecFlow 1.9.3.1 on Visual Studio 2013.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/specflow/sb38tqgDaq4/pAeprtPu_PcJ